# Xamarin - render barcode on Android devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Does anyone have any sample code I could use to render a code 128 barcode on the Xamarin mobile app, I have looked through an number of forums and found code snippets by struggled to get the environment set correctly in Visual Studio 2017 to build any project.

Comment: Have you look at https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile ?

Comment: "I have looked through an number of forums and found code snippets by struggled to get the environment set correctly in Visual Studio 2017 to build any project.". This doesn't give us any useful information, what have you tried? What is the error?